# Hyperlink to a part of a page that doesn't have an identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a hyperlink that goes directly to the data parameter of the $.ajax command.  But the closest hash tag that I can find is [this one](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings).

Q: Is there a way to have the browser navigate down to a part where there is no id= or name= attribute?  I'm thinking of maybe including some JavaScript into the url.

Comment: Are you trying to do this on your own page, or on a page you are linking to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently did this for a project using jQuery and the jQuery [ScrollTo plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo). It's quite simple.

**1. Include the jQuery and jQuery ScrollTo libraries on your page**

```
<script type="text/javscript"jquery.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.scrollTo-min.js" />
```

**2. Ask jQuery to scroll to some part of the page.** You can pass in any jQuery object (ie, and element, id selector etc). The second parameter is how long the scroll should take.

```
$.scrollTo($("#some_element_id_or_selector.with_a_class"), 1000);
```

In your description you've said there is no id on the element of interest, so try using other jQuery selectors. If you provide some more information about what you're trying to do I might be able to help more.

You can read more about the jQuery.scrollTo plugin [here](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html).

Comment: Thanks user407462!  It's trickier than that however because the page is not one of my pages.  I'm trying to create a hyperlink to a point on a page that's on a different server than mine.

Comment: So you click a link, it opens the page (loaded from a different server), and then scrolls down to part of the page?

Comment: Yes.  The link will have to have JavaScript in the url.  I suppose I can assume the jQuery site has jQuery loaded.

Comment: Unfortunately, in that case, I don't think you're going to be able to get it working. If you could, it might be a breach of the same-domain policy. You could create a bookmarklet that the user can click to scroll down the page, but that might not be what you're after.